# grunt call other tasks from the main task

Tags: javascript, node.js, gruntjs, npm

Sometimes you may wish to call other tasks from a main task.

Asume we have `build` and a `dist` tasks. By passing the option `--build` to the `dist` task, the `build` task should run *before*.

Unfortunately, the build task **repeats in an endless loop** ?

```
grunt dist --build
```

Example (short and simplified):

```
  // command: grunt build
  grunt.registerTask('build', 'Dist task', function() {

    grunt.initConfig({...}); // cssmin, htmlmin tasks etc...

    grunt.task.run(tasksArray); 
  });

  // command: grunt dist
  grunt.registerTask('dist', 'Build task', function() {

    // Option: --build
    var buildOption = grunt.option('build');

    if (buildOption != null) {
      grunt.task.run('build'); // Run the build task first
    }

    grunt.initConfig({...}); // compress task etc...

    grunt.task.run(tasksArray);
  });
```

How can I prevent the endless repeat of the build task?

---

Note:

Of course I *may* use something like: `grunt build && grunt dist`, but the example above is (as mentioned) a simplified example for something bigger.

Comment: What does `grunt.task.run(tasksArray);` contain? If it contains the `dist` task or any task that runs `dist`, it will loop.